# Making an Array Of Buttons All Respond Differently

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making a two-dimensional array of buttons for a game I'm making. The actual array holds instances of a square class, which has (among other things) the X and Y coords of where the button should go. The main "X coordinate" array is a class object, but the "Y coordinate" arrays are created programmatically, as are all the instances of the square class. So far, I've got the buttons showing in the proper locations, but I need a way for the buttons to know where they are in terms of X and Y coordinates. I want to make it so that when a button is clicked, its image changes to a "selected" state, but I don't know how to access the specific button that is clicked, since it's unconnected to the square object that holds the coords. I've been toying with using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, but I don't know how to pass the coords to a selector.

I don't think I'll need to post any code for this question, as I don't have an actual coding error, but if you'd like to see some of my code, or if you need more information, just ask, and I'd be happy to provide either.

Comment: You don't need to study the position of each button.Like rdurand says, you can give a different tag (also the title or the id) to each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using tags ? Set them with `button0.tag = 0, button1.tag = 1, ...`. When you add the action, pass the tag of the button, and in your action, update the button with the correct tag.

*Note: I may be wrong on this, I'm not sure I understood exactly your context, but that's how I would identify different elements of the same type, so it may be usable here :). If I'm totally wrong, I'm sorry.*

Comment: This is a really good answer. I'm going to let the question sit unanswered for a bit, just in case someone has a clever way to handle it in a more coordinate-based manner, but this is definitely viable.

Comment: No problem, I'd also be interested in knowing how other devs would handle this situation. :)

Comment: Actually, I can set up a way to convert tag numbers to coordinate values, so this will work perfectly. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Handling the coordinates would be simple, for all your buttons point them to the same selector if possible.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then on the buttonPressed: selector...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
CGRect buttonFrame = [sender frame];
float buttonXCoord = buttonFrame.origin.x;
float buttonYCoord = buttonFrame.origin.y;

// The rest of your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Good answer! I really like how the tags work, though, so I'm going to stick with them. However, I'm upvoting your answer, as it is still helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Any information that you assign to the button will be available in the target method by virtue of receiving a pointer to the button that was pressed.  If you need to know the coordinates of the button, then you can check its `frame` property, which contains both the origin and size of the button's bounding box.  Just make sure that you add the selector correctly in the add target method (it will end in a colon [:]) and set up the method correctly - `- (void)myButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender`